# Postgresql select and subselect in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I have following tables:

```
Table person:
id |      name |
---------------+
 1 |      adam |
 2 |     chris |
 3 |     nancy |
 4 |  nathalie |
 5 |      holy |


Table relation:
id | person | parent |
---+--------+--------+
 1 |      2 |      1 |
 2 |      2 |      3 |
 3 |      1 |      4 |
 4 |      5 |      2 |
```

I would like to have a query which produces something similar as this:

```
person |   parent |
-------+----------+
 chris |     adam |
 chris |    nancy |
  adam | nathalie |
  holy |    chris |
```

I'm not sure how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The `relation` table already shows who people's parents are. You just need to join it to the `person` tables (twice) to translate those IDs to names:

```
SELECT p1.name, p2.name
FROM   relation r
JOIN   person p1 ON p1.id = r.person
JOIN   person p2 ON p2.id = r.parent
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need two joins:

```
select pp.name as person, pa.name as parent
from relation r left join
     person pp
     on r.person = pp.id left join
     parent pa
     on r.parent = pa.id;
```

This uses `left join`, in case some of the values are not known (for instance, in case you don't know a person's parent).